# create image on nodejs with graphicsmagick

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphicsmagick

I need a way to create an image on graphicsMagick via node.js

Normally I can manage this with;

```
gm convert -background transparent -pointsize 30 -gravity Center label:türkçee HEEEEEY.png
```

I need the equivalent of this input in node.js like;

```
var gm = require('gm');
gm.background('transparent')
  .gravity('Center')
  .fontSize(30)
  .drawText('Test')
  .write('HEEEY.png')
```

PS: I don't want to give image size as parameter. (sorry for my english)

Comment: This is just a google away. http://aheckmann.github.com/gm/

Comment: I know that. It manuplates an image not creating a new one it.

Comment: i didnt fount a way to create a new one.

Answer (score 11):

Look in the [node-grapicksmagick README](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm), under "creating an image".

```
// creating an image
gm(200, 400, "#ddff99f3")
.drawText(10, 50, "from scratch")
.write("/path/to/brandNewImg.jpg", function (err) {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: but it creats an image 200x400 sized. I want the my image size just fits the text.

Comment: @Lupus what size do you want the text to be?